# Why is PowerShell not saving to working folder?

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that converts .xls files in a folder to .csv files. I have eight .xls files (although the number doesn't matter) to be converted to .csv, and they are located in **C:\Users\UserName\Documents\ABC\RawData\CSV\WorkingFolder**. The script works fine as far as converting .xls to .csv goes, but the problem is that the .csv files [after being created] are getting saved to **C:\Users\UserName\Documents**, which is the wrong location! I would like the .csv files to be saved to the same folder where the original .xls files are located: **C:\Users\UserName\Documents\ABC\RawData\CSV\WorkingFolder**, which is also the folder in which I am running the script. I have tried `-path .` to no avail. Any help would be appreciated! The script is as follows.

```
$excel = new-object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $True
$excel.Visible = $False
$src_dir = $(get-location).Path # this obtains the source location, but not sure how I might
# be able to use it
foreach ($file in get-childitem *.xls) {
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($file.FullName)
$wb.SaveAs($file.Name + ".csv", 6) # 6 -> csv
$wb.Close($True)
}
$excel.Quit()
[void][System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
get-childitem *.xls | foreach { remove-item -path $_.fullname }
# last line of script deletes the .xls files after they have been converted to .csv,
# more to unclutter than for anything else
```

Comment: `$file.Name` resolves to the name of the file, not the full path, so the file is saved to the current working directory (in the `$wb.SaveAs` step). If you use `$wb.SaveAs($file.FullName + ".csv", 6)` then you'll get the functionality you require.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get current location and give it as path

```
$localPath=(Get-Location).toString()
$wb.SaveAs($localPath + "\" + $file.Name + ".csv", 6) # 6 -> csv
```

Answer (score 2):

`$file.Name` represents the file name, not the full path to the file

When you are calling

`$wb.SaveAs($file.Name + ".csv", 6) # 6 -> csv`

You are telling Excel to save `nameofmyfile.xls.csv`, and it is saving it to the default folder location which is your documents folder.

What you need to call is

`$wb.SaveAs($file.FullName + ".csv", 6) # 6 -> csv`

Which will tell Excel to save `C:\Users\UserName\Documents\ABC\RawData\CSV\WorkingFolder\nameofmyfile.xls.csv` which should save the file to the expected folder location.